# npm install: 500 ERR

Tags: node.js, npm

When trying to install a package via npm from a private registry, an error 500 is returned.

[image]

But when I try to get through to the package I need with a curl, it returns to me without any problems. Please help me understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Please add more to the question: eg did you try `npm login`?

Comment: Will you please visit this link: https://stackabuse.com/npm-error-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-when-installing-module/